# Draggable in left and top %

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
$(function() {
  $('.dragElement').draggable({
    containment: "parent"
  }).filter('.dragElement').draggable("option", "axis");
});
```

```css
.one {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.dragElement {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid white;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
  <div class="dragElement">
  </div>
</div>
```

Please tell me, is there such a code. When you move an element, `left` and `top` are written in `px`. How to make this position be recorded in `%` relative to the parent.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can get the height and width of the parent (you can also use an event to recalculate them when resizing the window).

Then, using the `drag` method to get the `left` and `top` of the position, you can use a function to convert it to percentage using the current position and the parent height or width.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.dragElement').draggable({
    containment: "parent",
    drag: function(event, ui) {
      console.log(
        "top: "  + calcPerc(parentHeight, ui.position.top),
        "left: " + calcPerc(parentWidth, ui.position.left)           
      );
    }
  }).filter('.dragElement').draggable("option", "axis");
  
  function calcPerc(par, child) {
    return (100*child)/par;
  }
  
});

var parentEl = $(".one");
var parentHeight, parentWidth;

window.addEventListener('resize', recalcParent);

function recalcParent() {
  parentHeight = parseInt(parentEl.css('height'));
  parentWidth = parseInt(parentEl.css('width'));
}

recalcParent();
```

```css
.one {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.dragElement {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid white;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
  <div class="dragElement">
  </div>
</div>
```